# Why am I running into "The item with the specified name wasn't found" when creating a bar chart from a table of values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macros in Excel, where I am simply creating a bar chart from a table of values, but I am running into the error: "The item with the specified name wasn't found".

Here is the code:

```
Range("B2:C3,G2:I3,B7:C7,G7:I7").Select
    Range("G7").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'Q221 Insurers'!$B$2:$C$3,'Q221 Insurers'!$G$2:$I$3,'Q221 Insurers'!$B$7:$C$7,'Q221 Insurers'!$G$7:$I$7" _
        )
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 205
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 29").IncrementLeft -349.5 <------
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 29").IncrementTop 192
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 29").ScaleWidth 0.4656251094, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 29").ScaleHeight 0.6145833333, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 29").ScaleWidth 1.7203577726, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 29").ScaleHeight 1.4802259887, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

The error is taking place on the 10th line- the line `("Chart 29").IncrementLeft -349.5`

Any ideas why I aim running into this error?

For reference, here is the table I am pulling from:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its unlikely that the chart you created will be called "Chart 29". Assign the created chart to a reference and use that.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateGraph()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(205, xlColumnClustered)
    
    With shp
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Q221 Insurers'!$B$2:$C$3," & _
        "'Q221 Insurers'!$G$2:$I$3,'Q221 Insurers'!$B$7:$C$7,'Q221 Insurers'!$G$7:$I$7")
                                      
        .Chart.ClearToMatchStyle
        .Left = 0
        .Top = 200
        .ScaleWidth 0.8, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleHeight 0.91, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks CDP- but what do I do with the above code? Do I add it to my existing query, or do I replace my existing query with it?

Comment: @user what query ?, What code is above the lines you posted ? This code replaces your code.

Comment: Hi CDP- I realised it is because I am pulling the chart, then moving it to another sheet! I didn't realise you couldn't do this.

Comment: @user You can do that but it makes more sense to just create the chart in the sheet you want it in.

Comment: Thanks CDP, but if I create the chart in a different sheet, can I pull the data from another sheet?

Comment: @user Yes , have you tried it ?